# Typescript decorators - get decorator names of a property/class

Tags: typescript

For example:

```
class Person {  
    @test age:number;
}
```

I want to get the name of the decorators of the "age" property ("test"). Is it possible?

Comment: `@test int age` should be `@test age: number` instead.

Comment: It _should_ be possible using [ReflectDecorators](https://github.com/rbuckton/ReflectDecorators).

Comment: Where do you want to get this name? `test` is your own function, you know its name

Comment: Another class creates things based on the property decorators. I know its name, but I want my program to know its name also.

Comment: Thanks John White, I will look it up!