# How to get name of a method in NestJS via a decorator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, decorator, typescript-decorator

Related questions I found here:

1. [Get Method Name in TypeScript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59708987/get-method-name-in-typescript-class) - here I've got something useful.
2. [How to get method name in method decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54610521/how-to-get-method-name-in-method-decorator).
3. [Typescript decorators - get decorator names of a property/class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063119/typescript-decorators-get-decorator-names-of-a-property-class).
4. [Get Method Name in TypeScript class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64715203/how-to-get-method-name-in-typescript).

The problem: **I need to create a decorator or decorators to get Class name and method name.** It is necessary to create a convenient error handler that will log the location of the error in human-readable format.

What I have now:

Authorization/authentication controller (`gateway/src/auth.controller.ts`):

```ts
@ClassName // <---- It works, see the code in a listing below.
@Controller('auth')
@ApiTags('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    @Inject('USER_SERVICE') private readonly userServiceClient: ClientProxy,
  ) {
  }

  // @MethodName
  @Post('register')
  public async register(
    @Body() body: RegisterBodyDto,
  ): Promise<IResponse<{ user: IUser }>> {
    // @ts-ignore
    console.log('className:', this.__className); // Output: className: AuthController

    return await lastValueFrom(
      this.userServiceClient
        .send(USERS_EVENTS.USER_CREATE_USER, body)
        .pipe(timeout(MAX_TIME_OF_REQUEST_WAITING)),
    );
  }

  // ... etc.

}
```

The code of `ClassName` decorator (`gateway/src/common/decorators/class-name.decorator.ts`):

```ts
export function ClassName<T extends { new(...args: any[]): {}}>(target: T) {
  return class extends target {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
    }

    public __className: string = target.name;
  };
}
```

There is a code of a similar decorator for class methods and output in comments when I uncomment it in first listing (it doesn't work as I expect, `gateway/src/common/decorators/method-name.decorator.ts`):

```ts
export function MethodName<A extends any[], R>(
  target: Object,
  methodName: string,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(...args: A) => Promise<R>>,
) {
  const method = descriptor.value;

  console.log('target', target); // Output: target {}
  console.log('methodName', methodName); // Output: methodName register
  console.log('descriptor', descriptor);
  /* Output: 
  descriptor {
    value: [AsyncFunction: register],
    writable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
  }
  */
  console.log('descriptor.value', descriptor.value); // Output: descriptor.value [AsyncFunction: register]

  descriptor.value = async function(...args: A): Promise<R> {
    console.log(methodName); // <--- Doesn't work
    return await method.apply(target, args);
  };

  console.log('descriptor.value', descriptor.value); // Output: descriptor.value [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
}
```

When I uncomment `@MethodName` in first listing I've got 404 error:

> {
> "status": 404,
> "data": null,
> "errors": [
> "Cannot POST /api/v1/auth/register"
> ]
> }

Without the decorator it runs well.

So, how can I change the code of `MethodName` decorator to get a name of currently running method?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone else is looking for an answer.

I get method name by decorator like this:

```
export const GetMethodName = createParamDecorator(
  (data, context: ExecutionContext): string => {
    return context.getHandler().name;
  },
);
```

method.controller.ts

```
   async signIn(
        @GetMethodName() methodName: string,
        .......): Promise<any> {
        console.log(methodName) // => signIn
   }
```